# Is there a way to set an alias dynamically (i.e. result of another query) in SQL (MySQL 5.7)

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to create SQL views for some reports, and because it's only for reporting needs, I cannot change how tables are set.
I need to be able to name columns based on the result of another query, like some sort of key/value mapping. But may be there is another way.

I have tried using alias with sub-queries, or joins, but unfortunately I cannot manage to make it works. Any help or hint will really be appreciated.

I'm running MySQL 5.7.

To make it clearer, if we have 3 tables:

```
Fruits
+-----+--------+
| ID  | Value  |
+-----+--------+
|   1 | Apple  |
|   2 | Banana |
|   3 | Cherry |
| ... | ...    |
+-----+--------+


Vegetables
+-----+--------+
| ID  | Value  |
+-----+--------+
|   1 | Carrot |
|   2 | Onion  |
|   3 | Potato |
| ... | ...    |
+-----+--------+


Values
+--------+--------+--------+--------+-----+
| SomeId | Value1 | Value2 | Value3 | ... |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+-----+
|      1 | A1111  | B2222  | C3333  | ... |
|      2 | D4444  | E5555  | F6666  | ... |
|      3 | G7777  | H8888  | I9999  | ... |
|    ... | ...    | ...    | ...    | ... |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+-----+
```

*It's just a basic example.*

I expect the following outputs:

For Fruits

SELECT SomeId, Value1 as Apple, Value2 as Banana, Value3 as Cherry, ...

With Apple, Banana, Cherry, ... the result of another query.

```
Result
+--------+-------+--------+--------+-----+
| SomeId | Apple | Banana | Cherry | ... |
+--------+-------+--------+--------+-----+
|      1 | A1111 | B2222  | C3333  | ... |
|      2 | D4444 | E5555  | F6666  | ... |
|      3 | G7777 | H8888  | I9999  | ... |
|    ... | ...   | ...    | ...    | ... |
+--------+-------+--------+--------+-----+
```

For Vegetables

SELECT SomeId, Code1 as Carrot, Code2 as Onion, Code3 as Potato, ...

With Carrot, Onion, Potato, ... the result of another query.

```
Result
+--------+-------+--------+--------+-----+
| SomeId | Carrot| Onion  | Potato | ... |
+--------+-------+--------+--------+-----+
|      1 | A1111 | A2222  | A3333  | ... |
|      2 | B4444 | B5555  | C6666  | ... |
|      3 | D7777 | E8888  | F9999  | ... |
|    ... | ...   | ...    | ...    | ... |
+--------+-------+--------+--------+-----+
```

Comment: This requires dynamic SQL, which is more complex that standard SQL queries. If you have a reasonable number of views, you could be better off creating them manually.

Comment: Yep, this requires dynamic SQL, and maybe pivoting too.

Comment: I would write a stored procedure that would do it easily.

Comment: I think you can reference here for the solution https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/59062/how-can-i-dynamically-alias-columns